# Is there a way to get rid of these extra line in this cell with an image?

Tags: office365, microsoft-word-2016

I have marked the issue with red boxes:
[image: Screenshot of a table with 3 pictures]

I seem to be unable to get rid of this extra line. Is there any way to achieve that? I only need those pictures in this table and these extra line make the layout look bad.

Comment: That symbol is the **End Of Cell Marker** in tables. It cannot be directly deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, to remove the only line from a table in Word.

The only solution here was to bring the image to the front, instead of having "top and bottom" as layout option for the picture. This way the line gets hidden behind the images and does not warp the layout any more.

[image: Screenshot of solution]